# Div wont go into wrapper?

Tags: css, html, wrapper

I'm having a bit of trouble with a div, my website has one wrapper sized `height: 100%;` this wrapper contains various divs like a header, slider and a content div. The only problem is the content div gets pushed out of the wrapper div for some mysterious reason.

```
html {
    overflow-y:                         scroll;
    height:                             100%;
    position:                           relative;
}

a {
    outline:                            none;
}

img {
    width:                              100%;
    border:                             none;
    -moz-border-radius:                 20px;
    border-radius:                      20px;
}

body {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             100%;
    background-color:                   yellow;
    margin:                             0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    width:                              87%;
    height:                             100%;
    background-color:                   red;
    margin:                             0 auto;
}

.header {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             150px;
    background-color:                   green;
    float:                              left;
    overflow:                           hidden;
}

.logo {
    width:                              7%;
    height:                             114px;
    margin:                             18px 0% 18px 3%;
    float:                              left;
    background-image:                   url("..//img/logo.png");
    background-size:                    100%;
    background-repeat:                  no-repeat;  
}

.slogan {
    width:                              30%;
    height:                             100px;
    background:                         orange;
    margin:                             25px 13% 25px 13%;
    float:                              left;
}

.nav {
    width:                              31%;
    height:                             150px;
    background-color:                   purple;
    float:                              left;
    margin:                             0% 3% 0% 0%;
}

.search {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             50%;
    background:                         blue;
    float:                              left;
}

.menu {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             50%;
    float:                              left;
    background:                         grey;
}

.slider-container {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             100%;
    background-color:                   white;
}

.main-content {
    width:                              100%;
    height:                             100px;
    background-color:                   pink;
    float:                              left;
}

.column {
    width:                              31%;
    height:                             auto;
    background-color:                   orange;
    float:                              left
}

/* SLIDER */

.caption {
    width:                              500px;
    background-image:                   url("..//img/caption-bg.png");
    background-size:                    100%;
    position:                           absolute;
    z-index:                            99;
    overflow:                           hidden;
    margin-top:                         7%;
    margin-left:                        5%;
    -moz-border-radius:                 20px;
    border-radius:                      20px;
}

.caption-text {
    max-width:                          460px;
    overflow:                           hidden;
    margin:                             20px;
}

.wrapper .slider-container #slideshow { 
    float:                              left;
    position:                           relative; 
    width:                              100%;
}

.wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div { 
    position:                           absolute; 
}
```

You can see a live demo at http://k2stuc.nl/test/

Answer (score 0):

Setting `height: 100%` on the `<body>` sets its height to 100% of the viewport.

Now, the viewport is as high as the browser window's `inner-height`; and that changes when you resize the browser itself.

Any direct child of the `<body>`, set to `height: 100%` then inherits the viewport's height.

That's part of how a lot of the 'parallax' websites do their thing.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, is there any solution to still place the content div in the wrapper div?

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the wrapper div to contain all content except the footer, the footer will have a width of 100% for the header, slider and content it has to be in the wrapper so it's centered. It should all be dynamic. The order would then be header, slider, content

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question 100%. But I saw an issue, the navigation behind the slideshow is because your slides, `.wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div` has set to `position:absolute`.

Try setting `.slider-container` height to a fixed height. Otherwise slides will be above the content.

Comment: Yeah, i know that will fix it, but that would be my last resort, I want the slider height to be dynamic so that when you scale the browser it will maintain aspect ratio?

Comment: I would go with java scripts in this case. Sorry don't know about a pure css fix.

Answer (score 0):

you are floating things that should not be floated

i.e `.header`, `.main-content`,`#slideshow` - none of these need floats - body should not have `height:100%;`

give `.slide-container` a fixed height in pixels not a  percentage.. doing the above will fix your problem

Comment: Will this place the content div in the wrapper div?

Comment: yes it will.. you should only use floats when you're trying to display block elements alongside other block elements - using them how you have is actually making your `.main-content` sit behind the `.slide-container` as all your elements appear detached from each other

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem comes from the fact the slider div has `height:100%`

Comment: What can I change the slider div's height is so it still is dynamic

Comment: I don't really understand what you are looking for. If you want your slider-container to be adjusted to the content you need a fixed height because the slides of your slider are in `position:absolute`